# How to redirect example.com to example.com/mypath/mypage from vhost file

Tags: dns, httpd.conf, vhosts

**Problem statement:**

How to redirect `example.com` to `example.com/mypath/mypage` from vhost file

**Configurations done:**

1. Added below entries in vhost SSL and on SSL both & restarted httpd

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/mypath/mypage  [L,R=301]
   ```

**Issue:**
If user type `example.com` it should go to `https://www.example.com/mypath/mypage`, it's not happening

Answer (score 0):

you can use Apache's mod_rewrite module.

Open the vhost file for the domain you want to redirect.
Add the following lines of code to the file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /mypath/mypage [L,R=301]
```

Change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/mypath/mypage  
[L,R=301]
```

By

```
RewriteRule ^$ /mypath/mypage [L,R=301]
```